# How does Whirlwind Attack interact with Travel Devotion or other swift action movement?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, combat, movement

Since swift actions can be used during other actions, what happens if one uses a swift action movement (for example under the effect of Travel Devotion) in the middle of a Whirlwind Attack?

Would the character
A) continue making attacks while moving?
B) Interrupt the attacks with a  move?

In either case, would any "new"  enemy -  not present when beginning the attack but coming in range due to the character's movement - be a valid target for continuing the Whirlwind Attack?

(Note I'm asking for explicitly movement as a swift action, not a move action gained through a swift action)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108530/discussion-on-question-by-drejzer-how-does-whirlwind-attack-interact-with-travel).

Answer (score 2):

## They must be done separately

[*Whirlwind attack*](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Whirlwind_Attack) states:

> When you use the full attack action, you can **give up your regular
>   attacks** and instead make **one melee attack** at your full base attack
>   bonus against **each opponent** within reach.
>
> When you use the Whirlwind Attack feat, you also forfeit any bonus or
>   extra attacks granted by other feats, spells, or abilities

A full attack action requires an entire [round](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm) (Standard+ Movement/2movements/A full round action) (5-foot step movement is sometimes not possible) **You can do swift actions in those rounds if you can and some free actions can be done also.**

*Travel Devotion* states (and explains it):

> Benefit Once per day as a swift action, you can activate this ability
>   to move up to your speed as a swift action each round. **Thus, you can
>   move your speed and then take a full-round action, or move and take
>   two other actions** (**two move actions or one move action and one
>   standard action**). This effect lasts for 1 minute.
>
> Special **You cannot take a 5-foot step in the same round that you use
>   this feat to move as a swift action**.

So in total:

- 2 move actions +move your speed

  or
- 1 move action +move your speed +1 standard

  or
- 1 Full round action +move your speed

Knowing that, you can either use *Whirlwind attack* first then take your movement from *Travel Devotion* or start with your movement then do your Whirlwind attack.

Whirlwind attack makes you use your movement action without even moving, you just spin around and hit multiple ennemies in one attack (that hits multiple creatures and must roll for each hits), you can't move while doing so (mounted combat could be another question but I don't think it would work). It just takes too much time so you have to use your ''movement action time'' to do so.

## Also

- Only immediate actions (that counts as swift action for your next
  turn) can be used during the turn of another creature wich *travel
  devotion* is not. If a creature could indeed interupt the attacker
  and move out of the range via another ability such as *abrupt jaunt*,
  yes the character is safe or readying an action to move out of the range
  if the ennemy attacks would work too.

> **Full Attack**
>
> If you get more than one attack per round because your    base attack bonus is high enough, because you fight with two weapons    or
>   a double weapon or for **some special reason you must use a
>
>   full-round action to get your additional attacks**. You do not need to
>   specify the targets of your attacks ahead of time. You can see how
>   the earlier attacks turn out before assigning the later ones.
>          **The only movement you can take during a full attack is a 5-foot step.    You may take the step before, after, or between your
>   attacks**.

- Since it specifies: ''or for some special reason you must use a
  full-round action to get your **additional attacks**'' and that
  Whirlwind attack does indeed says: ''you can **give up your regular
  attacks and instead make one melee attack**''  I'm not even sure you
  can use the 5 foot movement in between attacks. It is a full attack
  action as mentionned but for this part I need [help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/168325/51979)* I guess.

  **But if you used Travel Devotion's swift action in the same round you can't do this, and if you used the 5 foot step bye bye the extra movement from *Travel Devotion*.**

*[Are the attacks made when using the Whirlwind Attack feat sequential or simultaneous?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/168325/51979)

## Conclusion

It is the Dm's call if Whirlwind Attack is sequential or simultaneous but it is very reasonable to allow the 5 foot step movement and make it sequential and you can indeed be interrupted anytime during this period by an immediate action (or a well placed readied action), the Dervish Dancer can do it better anyways so as for The Travel Devotion extra movement I personally would not allow it to work within the Whirlwind attack  nor I believe it works that way one reason for me is because it would make the Dervish Dancer unique ability obsolete (5 times per day max) and that you can normally only move 5 feet DURING a full attack. For Dance of Death you cannot redo it for 5 rounds after you use it so it's less powerful.  See [KRyan's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/168334/51979) on the matter here for more details.

Comment: Travel Devotion does not give a move action, it just lets you move your speed. You can't combine it with a standard action to get a full-round action, or use it for any other move action aside from moving. The usual source of an extra move action is the _hustle_ psionic power.

Comment: The benefit explains what it does and does say it's an extra move you can do.... as a swift action. But ok I see what you mean, but any source that says you can't combine it?

Comment: There doesn’t need to be one: Travel Devotion never once says anything about a move action, which is what you need in order to anything you use move actions for. It just says that you move your speed, nothing else.

Comment: Ah because you can't do anything else than move as for a move action you can do other things I see ok fair enough thank you senpai KRyan.

Comment: @KRyan do you have any info on the Linked question I asked?

Comment: I’m writing an answer, but it’s not going to help much.

Comment: Dm's call I guess xD

Comment: But... I always read Whirlwind Attack as giving you a single attack against every enemy in reach (as in : there are 5 enemies in reach - you get 5 attacks, one Attacks against each one of them)