# Are the attacks made when using the Whirlwind Attack feat sequential or simultaneous?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, attack

This way we will know if we can use the 5 foot step during the whirlwind attack and if another creature can use an immediate action while it's being done:
Of course you can use the 5 foot step before or after but can you use it while doing the attack so you could have an increased reach?

Edited as suggested by @Hey I Can Chan

Comment: Since you can choose your targets and is not an aoe attack, it makes it even more confusing.

Comment: Old discussion here:https://www.enworld.org/threads/whirlwind-attack-and-5-foot-step.87428/      And people interpret it differently,   PF but same rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feat is fundamentally ambiguous.

> one melee attack [...] against each opponent within reach

<sup>([Whirlwind Attack](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#whirlwindAttack))</sup>

Is this one attack, total, that is resolved against each target within melee reach, or is this one attack *for each* target within reach? The English language allows this wording to mean either of those things, and the feat gives absolutely no additional context that can resolve the ambiguity.

The *closest* we have here is the general definition of an attack: rolling an attack roll against a single target’s AC. If we were making one attack total, there would need to be a singular attack roll, which has to be resolved against multiple target’s ACs. This isn’t a problem, per se, and there are things in the game that do that, but they *explicitly say they do that*. Whirlwind Attack doesn’t. Maybe that’s telling. Maybe.

Note that we don’t even need to get into questions of free actions, swift actions, or immediate actions for this to be a problem, because it’s also a question of how many times you make an attack roll, and how critical threats and hits get resolved. If it’s one attack, and you roll a nat-20, do you threaten a critical hit against every target? If so, do you roll your critical confirmation once and compare against everything’s AC, or do you roll separately for each? And if you roll well, do you crit everything all at once? This is, to me, another reason to favor multiple attacks, because that is horribly swingy.

Anyway, if it’s one attack total, it’s one attack and nothing can happen “between attacks” because there’s only one attack and nothing to be “between.” If it’s multiple attacks, then yes, you can definitely take a 5-foot step between those attacks:

> When you use the full attack action,

<sup>([Whirlwind Attack](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#whirlwindAttack))</sup>

> The only movement you can take during a full attack is a 5-foot step. You may take the step before, after, or **between your attacks**.

<sup>([Full Attack](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#fullAttack), **emphasis** mine)</sup>

> You can take a 5-foot step before, **during**, or after your other actions in the round.

<sup>([Take 5-Foot Step](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#take5FootStep), **emphasis** mine)</sup>

Likewise, immediate actions are definitely on the table, since

> an immediate action can be performed at any time — even if it's not your turn

<sup>([Immediate Actions](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#immediateActions))</sup>

If it’s possible to 5-foot step between attacks, that is clearly “a time” and since immediate actions are green-lit for “any time,” that one counts.

Free and swift actions are less clear, however.

> ### Free Actions
>
> Free actions don’t take any time at all, though there may be limits to the number of free actions you can perform in a turn. Free actions rarely incur attacks of opportunity. Some common free actions are described below.

<sup>([Free Actions](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#freeActions))</sup>

This is literally all we get on free actions, which really doesn’t tell us *anything* about when they can be used beyond the suggestion—which isn’t even explicit—that they are things that only happen on your own turn.

And then swift actions just say

> You can take a swift action any time you would normally be allowed to take a free action.

<sup>([Swift Actions](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#swiftActions))</sup>

I.e. any of those times that the rules for free actions totally didn’t define at all, besides the implicit requirement that they be during your own turn.

So for the linked discussion, it’s not at all clear what effect Travel Devotion might have here. But since we know 5-foot steps are on the table, what does *that* mean?

Again, no one knows. I mean, if you use Whirlwind Attack, attack several targets but not all you can reach, and then 5-foot step, should you now also be able to attack all the targets you can reach from your new position? They are, after all, “within reach,” and you are still in the middle of your Whirlwind Attack, because your 5-foot step occurred “during” it which you are explicitly allowed to do. Or is “within reach” only evaluated when you first begin a Whirlwind Attack? There’s no telling. For that matter, even if we don’t re-evaluate “within reach,” could we move around to, say, get flanking bonuses on multiple targets? Maybe!—probably?!

The only thing that’s clear to me is that the author of this feat almost-certainly didn’t consider any of this. They almost-certainly treated the operation as atomic, whether it’s one attack or multiple. Which is maybe an argument for treating it that way. On the other hand, Whirlwind Attack is atrocious and could use all the benefits it can get.

But then I’m going to complicate things still further: look at *Complete Warrior*’s dervish prestige class, which gets

> **Dervish Dance (Ex):** A dervish can become a whirling dancer of death a certain number of times per day. While in this dervish dance, she can take a full attack action (for melee attacks only) and still move up to her speed. However, the dervish must move a minimum of 5 feet between each attack when using this ability, and she cannot return to a square she just exited (though she may return to that square later during her full attack). The dervish is subject to attacks of opportunity while dancing, but may tumble normally as part of her move. A dervish prevented from completing her move is also prevented from finishing her full attack.

<sup>(*Complete Warrior* pg. 26)</sup>

This is explicitly a full-attack, i.e. when you start a dervish dance, you can also choose to use Whirlwind Attack. How does *that* work? Seems to me that you should be able to attack everyone who is ever within your reach at any point in your movement, provided you have moved at least 5 feet since the last attack. Dervish requires Combat Expertise, Dodge, and Mobility too, so it’s kind of setting you up to take Whirlwind Attack (though it still isn’t worth it).

By the way, while we’re looking at the dervish, there is another thing worth bringing up here. Enter Paimon, the Dancer. Paimon is a vestige from *Tome of Magic*, and a binder who makes a pact with him is granted several abilities, including

> *Dance of Death:* When you use this ability, you can move up to your speed and make a single attack against any creature you move past, provoking attacks of opportunity normally. When you use your dance of death, you forfeit any bonus or extra attacks granted by other feats or abilities (such as the Cleave feat or the *haste* spell), and you cannot attack any single creature more than once. Once you have used this ability, you cannot do so again for 5 rounds.

<sup>(*Tome of Magic* pg. 44)</sup>

> *Whirlwind Attack:* You gain the benefit of the Whirlwind Attack feat.

<sup>(*Tome of Magic* pg. 44)</sup>

Dance of death probably isn’t compatible with Whirlwind Attack (doesn’t say it’s a full attack, blocks “extra or bonus attacks” from feats),<sup>1</sup> and even if it was it’s not clear that there would be any benefit to doing so (you already get to attack everyone you can reach during the dance). But it does give an illustration of what dervish dance plus Whirlwind Attack might look like—and it’s from something called “the Dancer,” which also grants Whirlwind Attack explicitly.

1. <sub>I can make counter-arguments against both points. The reference to blocking extra or bonus attacks would be redundant unless this is a full-attack, since the only way to get such things *without* a full-attack is with the then-unpublished Snap Kick feat from *Tome of Battle*, which maybe implicitly makes this a full attack. And then Whirlwind Attack isn’t *really* “extra or bonus attacks,” not like *haste* or Cleave are. It’s a replacement. This isn’t really a strong argument, but just for the sake of argument. It doesn’t matter anyway.</sub>

Comment: What would be the best thing do to? I guess we can allow the 5 foot step since the dervish Dancer can already to better, I guess you roll for each attack and you can be interrupted between each of them? or just if you move? I'd allow it because melee characters need love, perhaps one roll could be balanced too, because you can miss all of them too (talking about the net 20 critical), Both are acceptable but I wonder what should be done between the 2.

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier I definitely don’t like the “one roll resolution” interpretation—too swingy, whatever else it does. Anyway, I’d allow 5-foot step during, and I’d allow attacks against any targets newly in reach, too. I say “would” because I literally cannot think of any time any players of mine or in games I’ve played in has actually taken Whirlwind Attack.

Comment: On a side note, I wanted to mention dervish in my question, but decided it would be too tangential...

Comment: @KRyan so you would allow immediate action from other creatures between each attacks as well?

Comment: On a side note, a single roll resolution world make it fall under volley rules for things like Sneak Attack or Skirmish, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier Yes, I would.

Comment: @Drejzer Maybe?? The volley rules were an awkward band-aid hack applied after the fact, and while they have a purpose (sneak-attack-on-every-beam *scorching ray* might be problematic at low levels), they aren’t nearly as clear or well-considered as I’d like.